# Creating an Application Page in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, application-pages

I just joined this forum today in hopes that someone here might be able to assist me with something I have been trying to develop for my company in SharePoint 2010.

Essentially, I have been tasked with creating a virtual "Application" page for the associates that work in our building to be able to apply for a promoted position. We are making this transition as in previous years, the application process was completed by having the associates fill out paper forms and submit them to their managers. Due to the increasingly massive scope and nature of our business, this no longer seems like a practical means of accepting applications as the physical forms are continually getting lost or misplaced.

So the idea now is for us to go virtual with everything...and currently the best tool my company has to make this happen is SharePoint 2010.

While I am in no way a "SharePoint Expert", I have dabbled with our page here and there and understand the basics of how to create and edit pages using SharePoint Designer.

I have looked at the SharePoints of other buildings in our network and found a pretty solid example of what I'm looking to create:

[image: Application Example]

So essentially my question is, how do I create a page exactly like this? Based on what I can see on the rest of their site, their associates can go to a computer they have set up, fill in their information in the page above, hit submit and then the department leadership is able to review all of the applications and results in a spreadsheet and evaluate each individual based on the results they submit.

I have considered that this could be a survey page, but every time I get down to specifics, I have trouble developing it the way it appears in the above picture.

If anyone here could provide me with any kind of guidance as far as what type of page this is and just how I could get started with creating it, your assistance would be GREATLY appreciated.

Generally with these sorts of projects once I at least get the ball rolling, I am able to figure out the rest along the way using google and other utilities like this site.

Any responses are welcome. Please let me know if there is any additional information you need from me or any questions that I can answer.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I would use infopath (but you need Sharepoint Enterprise for it) to achieve that (i prefer it for form design to SP Designer)

1. Create a list with all the fields that you will require.
2. Then use option from to Ribbon to modify the list form using infopath.
3. Make modifications in infopath.
4. Publish infopath.

And here is handy [guide](http://blogs.wrox.com/article/customizing-sharepoint-2010-list-forms-with-infopath-2010/) for most common actions in infopath.